# Deploy app with dokku to default http port (80)

Tags: digital-ocean, dokku

I have a problem having my application accessible through standard 8080 port on digital ocean. My DNS settings is:
example.com is linked to some completely different IP
api.example.com is linked to my digital ocean droplet IP.

My dokku instance VHOST file is set to "api.example.com" and HOSTNAME file also to "api.example.com". After I push my application to this dokku instance, the last line says "Application deployed: http://api.example.com". However even after this, my application is not accessible on api.example.com but only on api.example.com:49204.

I think I miss something but I don't know what, because I was not able to find a tutorial dealing with the exact strings that need to be configured for dokku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dokku config:unset NO_VHOST
```

fixed the issue in my case